# spring mapping isn't detected

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml

i have made a maven project trying to make an mvc program but things getting hard at the fisrt attempts,

[this is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz2PB.png)

[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNj94.png)

[springmvc-servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAjSC.png)

[my simple controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vvNi.png)

[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2nzZ.png)

finally all jars are uploaded in pom.xml

please can anyone help with this simple prolem that confise me

Comment: Please include your code as text. Check this guide on [formatting code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:
instead this **entry** in your sping config file
`<context:component-scan base-package="main.java.ma.gov"/>`
**change to:**
`<context:component-scan base-package="ma.gov"/>`
Probably Spring can't find your controller.

Comment: this exactly the solution thank you @Anthony